# How to build data for promotion in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-2.0

- I want to build some promotion price for products for listing by elasticsearch 2.3. The price will be changed by current time.
- Example: Product A 3 - 5pm: 3$ / 4 - 4.30pm: 2$. If the current time is 4.15pm, the price will be 2$. After 4.30pm, it will be 3$.
- I can't find the solution for elasticsearch 2.3. I should use inner object, nested or parent/child. Can you help me?

Comment: Why are you using elastic 2.3....?

Comment: because it's my old system.